# Asking for help on stackoverflow and programmers.stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, software-engineering-se, cross-posting

I would like to ask whether I can ask the same question on Stack Overflow and on programmers.stackexchange.com or it would be treated as a spam.

The reason to ask is because I am a new user here but I couldn't find an answer of this concern in the F.A.Q. The tag from which I am interested has more followers in Stack Overflow but at the same time I have already [asked in programmers.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/175606/qt-question-hard-coded-shortcuts?noredirect=1) where I didn't receive any answers.

Comment: Most often questions don't fit on both sites. And even if they do, cross-site duplicates are frowned upon. So I would not advice you to ask the same question again on a different site. There are other ways to get attention for unanswered questions. P.s. your question has been migrated to SO now.

Comment: your question has been [migrated from Programmers to SO](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/175606/qt-question-hard-coded-shortcuts) few minutes ago. As for cross-posting, it is officially _"strictly frowned upon as it leads to fragmented answers splattered all over the network"_ (quote source: [cross-posting tag wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/cross-posting/info))

Answer (score 4):

The two sites address different topics. You can check out the two site's FAQs for more comprehensive details, but in general, the "technical" questions go on StackOverflow("Why does this RegExp not match this string"), and the higher level, design, and procedure questions go into programmers.stackexchange("What's the benefit of following the following Agile process.").

It's unlikely that you'll have a question that fits into both of these categories.

Comment: Note: **tools** of programming (IDE, source control, etc) also belongs at Stackoverflow